# two way binding with addListener in angularjs 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not able to bind global variable.

here my code.

```
mxEvent.addListener(img, 'click',
            mxUtils.bind(this, function(evt:any) {
                this.enableRightSideBar = true;
                console.log(this.enableRightSideBar);
            }.bind(this))
        )

console.log(this.enableRightSideBar, 'this.enableRightSideBar');
```

Show me "true", but it's not reflected on html.

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where in Angular2 do you have this code? What and where is `mxUtils`?

Comment: mxUtils is mxgraph class

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
I am trying this Also:

 mxEvent.addListener(img, 'click', function(event:any) {
            this.enableRightSideBar = true;
        })
Not working for me.

Comment: You need to show us what `mxEvent` and `mxUtils` actually is. Or no one will be able to give you a correct answer.

Comment: What is output for `console.log(this)`?

Comment: Contain class functions and global variables

Comment: Have you tried to use `cd.detectChanges()`?

Comment: Not yet. How we use this.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072026/hostbiding-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-previous-value-hidden-c/40072227#40072227 Like this `this.enableRightSideBar = true; this.cd.detectChanges();`

Comment: @yurzui thanks , it's working

Comment: I think you should accept Günter's answer. it's his idea

Comment: @yurzui Can you please add this to answer so i can accept and reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much information in your question but I guess this is what you need to do:

```
mxEvent.addListener(img, 'click', (event:any) => { this.enableRightSideBar = true; })
```

**Update**

Seems this callback is fired outside angular zone so you can use ChangeDetectorRef to refresh view:

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...
this.enableRightSideBar = true; 
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: When i try to change 
this.enableRightSideBar = true;
Using button event. Its working fine but it's not working with addListener.

Comment: Have you considered providing more information as mentioned 2 times above already?

Comment: The 3rd time: Please provide more context. Where in Angular2 do you have this code? Please edit your question and add more code that shows where you have the code in your question.