# HostBiding expression has changed after it was checked.Previous value 'hidden' current value 'hidden'

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to animate the height of an the host element using angulars animation api. Here is my code:

```js
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from "@angular/core";

export class SlideToggleOption {
    public static AnimationName: string = "slideToggle";
    public static Visible: string = "visible";
    public static Hidden: string = "hidden";
}

export function SlideToggleAnimation() {
    return trigger(SlideToggleOption.AnimationName, [
        state(SlideToggleOption.Visible, style({ height: "auto", overflow: "hidden" })),
        state(SlideToggleOption.Hidden, style({ height: 0, overflow: "hidden" })),

        transition(
            `${SlideToggleOption.Visible} => ${SlideToggleOption.Hidden}`,
            animate("5000ms ease-in")
        ),
        transition(
            `${SlideToggleOption.Hidden} => ${SlideToggleOption.Visible}`,
            animate("5000ms ease-out")
        ),
    ]);
}

import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, ElementRef, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";
import { SlideToggleAnimation, SlideToggleOption } from "./../../animations/slide-toggle.animation";

@Component({
    selector: "dropdown-menu",
    moduleId: module.id,
    styleUrls: ["dropdown-menu.style.css"],
    templateUrl: "dropdown-menu.view.html",
    animations: [SlideToggleAnimation()],
})
export class DropdownMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() menuItems;
    @Input() position;
    @Input() isDropdownMenuVisible: boolean;

    @HostBinding("class") hostItemPositionClass;
    @HostBinding("@slideToggle") dropdownAnimationState = SlideToggleOption.Hidden;

    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.element = elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.element.parentElement.style.position = "relative";
        this.hostItemPositionClass = `menu-container-${this.position}`;
        this.dropdownAnimationState = SlideToggleOption.Hidden;
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.dropdownAnimationState = this.isDropdownMenuVisible
            ? SlideToggleOption.Visible
            : SlideToggleOption.Hidden;
    }
}
```

This is my html:

```html
<div class="menu-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems">
    <icon iconClass="{{menuItem.icon}}"></icon>
    <span>{{menuItem.text}}</span>
</div>
```

When I use this component the html looks like this:

```html
<button class="btn-icon" (click)="isMoreDropdownMenuVisible = !isMoreDropdownMenuVisible">
    <icon iconClass="icon-more"></icon>
</button>
<dropdown-menu
    [menuItems]="navSectionRightItems"
    [position]="dropdownMenuPosition"
    [isDropdownMenuVisible]="isMoreDropdownMenuVisible">
</dropdown-menu>
```

In the parent component [isMoreDropdownMenuVisible] is a boolean that has its default set to false.

I have omitted [menuItems] and [position] properties as they are not relevant to the current problem.

When I click the button with a class of btn-icon I get the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Angular doesn't like when change detection causes changes. `ngOnInit()` is called by change detection.

To work around inject `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and call `detectChanges()` after modifying properties to invoke change detection explicitly

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.element.parentElement.style.position = 'relative';
    this.hostItemPositionClass = `menu-container-${this.position}`;
    this.dropdownAnimationState = SlideToggleOption.Hidden;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Or just initialize everything in the constructor, which is really the recommended usage of the constructor ;-)

Comment: Sure, but that's not always possible.